# emptydatarowstyle is not working

Tags: asp.net

I have a `emptydatarowstyle` that doesn't seem to be working.  When the GridView is empty. I'm trying to hide the white border around this:

[image]

Code:

```
<emptydatarowstyle  BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" />

                    <emptydatatemplate>

                    No Dates Found for this experience at this current time.  Please try again.

                    </emptydatatemplate>
```

EDIT:

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="book.aspx.cs" Inherits="chinatownexperience.book" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- Put the following javascript before the closing </head> tag. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var cx = '000935526448861961589:s0c0yzdtfao';
        var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
        gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
    })();
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="body-1">
        <div id="topblank">
                <div class="top-1-1"><a href="experiences.aspx"><img onmouseover="this.src='images/myexperience-on.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/myexperience.png'" src="images/myexperience.png" width="111" height="23" alt="My Experience" /></a></div>
                <div class="yellowsquare"></div>
                <div class="top-1-2"><a href="loginpublic.aspx"><img onmouseover="this.src='images/login-on.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/login.png'" src="images/login.png" width="49" height="23" alt="Login" /></a></div>
                <div class="yellowsquare"></div>
                <div class="top-1-3"><a href="register.aspx"><img onmouseover="this.src='images/register-on.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/register.png'" src="images/register.png" width="62" height="23" alt="Register" /></a></div>
                <div class="top-2-google"><gcse:searchbox-only></div>
        </div>

        <div class="center">
            <div class="navhome"><a href="index.aspx"><img src="images/menu-home-button-off.png" width="81" height="54" alt="Home" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navaboutus"><a href="aboutus.aspx"><img src="images/menu-aboutus-button-off.png" width="105" height="54" alt="Home" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navexperiences"><a href="experiences.aspx"><img src="images/menu-experiences-button-on.png" width="129" height="54" alt="Home" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navgetinvolved"><a href="getinvolved.aspx"><img src="images/menu-getinvolved-button-off.png" width="130" height="54" alt="Home" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navsupportus"><a href="supportus.aspx"><img src="images/menu-supportus-button-off.png" width="128" height="54" alt="Home" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navcontactus"><a href="contactus.aspx"><img src="images/menu-contactus-button-off.png" width="132" height="54" alt="Home" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navmenuend"><img src="images/menu-end.png" width="8" height="54" alt="menu end" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="line"><hr /></div>

        <div class="centergrid">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CssClass="bookgridview">

<%--                <emptydatarowstyle  BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" />--%>

                    <emptydatatemplate>

                    Unfortunately, this Experience is currently fully booked. Please try again later for availability.

                    <!-- <div id="filler"></div>  -->

                    </emptydatatemplate> 

                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TName" HeaderText="Experience" SortExpression="TName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SDate" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="SDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="STime" HeaderText="Time" SortExpression="STime" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TDuration" HeaderText="Duration (approx)"
                        SortExpression="TDuration" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TPriceadult" HeaderText="Adult" 
                        SortExpression="TPriceadult" DataFormatString="{0:C}"  /> 
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TPricesenior" HeaderText="Student/Senior" 
                        SortExpression="TPricesenior" DataFormatString="{0:C}"  /> 
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TPricechild" HeaderText="Child" 
                        SortExpression="Tpricechild" DataFormatString="{0:C}"   /> 

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ScheduleId" HeaderText="ScheduleId" 
                        SortExpression="ScheduleId"  Visible="False" />
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkSelect" runat='server' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/bookingform.aspx?ID={0}", Eval("ScheduleId")) %>'>Book</asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ChinatowndbConnString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [vwSchedule] Where TourId=@tid">

                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:QueryStringParameter DbType="Int32" Name="tid" QueryStringField="tourid" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

        </div>

        <div id="bottomspace"></div>
        <div class="line"><hr class="top" /></div>             


    </div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.bookgridview 
{
    float: left;
    width: 836px;
    border: 1px solid white; 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font: 14px "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;  
}

.bookgridview td {   
    padding: 2px;   
}

.bookgridview th {   
    padding: 2px;    
}
```

Regards
Tea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dissected your page.See image below.

[image]

And after performing the magic in the row databound. You can see that the style bookgridview is the culprit.So we are clearing it by setting the css to an empty string.

[image]

End result.You can see now that the border is removed.Let me know how this goes.
[image]

Comment: I've added the grid CSS code to my question.  I need that code to format the Grid when there is data.

Comment: Your css style will be applied  normally when there is some data.The code only executes in an empty data row

Comment: I'll give the 100 points for effort, though its not working for me for some strange reason.  Thanks again for your effort.

Comment: I need that line else how am I to have a white 1px border when I do have data in my viewgrid?

Comment: You don't have to remove the line.I am saying that if you don't clear the style in the row data bound event of the empty row then it is the one putting a white border in your empty data template row.

Comment: This line in your bookgridview "border: 1px solid white;" will affect your empty data row if its not cleared by removing the css style in the row databound event of your gridview.

Comment: You mean remove class="bookgridview" from the GridView code?  But how then do I CSS my grid for when I have data?

Comment: In the code behind can I not CSS the grid from there for when there is data?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22403/discussion-between-abide-masaraure-and-teadrinkinggeek)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm not going to spend another minute on this problem.  I got a lot of other work to do and this is not worth it for a minor error.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are loosing the style after removing it  in the empty datarow  then add it back like this.You dont have to remove it in the markup.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridView bookingGridView = (GridView)sender;
            bookingGridView.CssClass = "bookgridview";

        }

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow)
        {
            GridView bookingGridView = (GridView)sender;

            bookingGridView.Attributes.Add("border", "0");
            bookingGridView.CssClass = "";

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your problem and figured out that on the rendered html table of the grid view , it comes with a bonus  border="1" attribute  added to it.No matter how you try setting your style to the empty data row , it is overridden by this parent attribute.I discovered this using firebug tools as well as Opera dragon fly .Both tools confirmed that this nasty border attribute will be added.

Then  I approached the problem this way

**Markup**

```
   <EmptyDataTemplate>
        Ooops. No rows to display.
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
```

**Code behind**
Add these lines of code  in your gridview row databound event and see the magic

```
   Protected Sub TestGridView_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles TestGridView.RowDataBound
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow Then

      CType(sender,GridView).Attributes.Add("border","0")
      CType(sender,GridView).CssClass=""

 End If
 End Sub
```

This works perfectly in all browsers.See sample below!!!
[image: See result]

Comment: How to add a datagridview row databound event?

Comment: I converted it to C#, unfortunately didn't work, the border is still there.

Comment: Can you post your aspx file so that I can have a look.Make sure that you have no other style overriding your grid css class.What style is being applied to your grid if you put a breakpoint on the line  CType(sender,GridView).CssClass="".And have you tried checking your page in firebug.Surely you will be able to see the offending culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try this approach.

### add to your css file

```
tr.empty-row, tr.empty-row td
{
  border: none;
}
```

### add inside your gridview

```
<EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="empty-row" />
```

If it's not working, try to set your boder color the same then your background.